# Zombie/Infected movie ending with a lady and a child handing some kind of cure to someone in a "safe zone"

Tags: story-identification, movie, zombie

The only thing I can remember that stood out was the ending. A lady and another adult or large child arrives to a place that looks like a safe haven and hands someone what looks like a cure. I can’t remember anything else about the movie except that one part.

Comment: When did you see it? Was it spoken in english? Was the safe haven above ground or underground? Did the lady hand over the cure, or the child/other? Was the child/other male or female (or not clear)?

Answer (score 18):

Question is a bit terse, but that immediately made me think of the theatrical ending of *I Am Legend* (2007). *(note that there's an alternate ending which is more faithful to the book)*

From [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0480249/?ref_=nv_sr_1):

> Robert Neville is a scientist who was unable to stop the spread of the terrible virus that was incurable and man-made. Immune, Neville is now the last human survivor in what is left of New York City and perhaps the world. For three years, Neville has faithfully sent out daily radio messages, desperate to find any other survivors who might be out there. But he is not alone. Mutant victims of the plague -- The Infected -- lurk in the shadows... watching Neville's every move... waiting for him to make a fatal mistake. Perhaps mankind's last, best hope, Neville is driven by only one remaining mission: to find a way to reverse the effects of the virus using his own immune blood. But he knows he is outnumbered... and quickly running out of time.

The ending below has Anna, a female survivor, and her kid Ethan bringing a "cure" vial to a stronghold, after

> Neville successfully developed said cure, but died protecting them from the creatures.